# Undefined reference to Logger::getInstance() - but only in some cases

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, undefined-reference, log4cplus

I'm using log4cplus (compiled from current git master), but i get undefined reference errors by the linker. However, these errors occur *only at some classes*.

In general each class has the following form:

#### Header (.h)

```
// ...
#include <log4cplus/loggingmacros.h>
// ...    
// namespace(s)

class Example
{
public:
    // ...
private:
    // ...
    static const log4cplus::Logger logger;
};
```

#### Source (.cpp)

```
// includes

// namespace(s)

// implementations

const log4cplus::Logger Example::logger = log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("Example"));
```

#### Usage

The logger is used within the class like this:

```
LOG4CPLUS_WARN(logger,  "Ha, ha – whatever you try I wont work!");
```

While compiling works, the linker raises an undefined reference error for

```
log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(std::string const&)
```

and

```
log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::string const&, char const*, int, char const*)
```

for some classes. I've already copied the logger-parts from working classes: same result.

Replacing the static logger by a class-member doesn't work neither – `getInstance()` isn't found.

What workarounds this problem is using the root-logger instead; this will compile / link (even though `getRoot()` is part of the same class!?):

```
const log4cplus::Logger Example::logger = log4cplus::Logger::getRoot();
```

But then there's the undefined reference error to

```
log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(...)
```

---

To be sure there's no typo, i've used those macros for declaration / definition:

```
#define LOG_DECL(name)      static const log4cplus::Logger logger
#define LOG_DEF(name)       const log4cplus::Logger name::logger = log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT(#name))
```

Same result, those which worked before worked too, and those which not … not.

---

#### More information:

1. Log4cplus is linked using -llog4cplusSU (also tested with log4cplusS) and was compiled from it's git master
2. GCC 4.9 – C++11 is used
3. Eclipse CDT for building the project
4. Log4cplus is initialized in the main
5. All classes are compiled using the same compiler and flags
6. Fully clean-and-build project
7. All files are compiled / linked the same way
8. const / not const has no effect

Result of `nm <NAME>.o | grep -i log4cplus`:

**Working object**

```
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6detail16macro_forced_logERKNS_6LoggerEiRKSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEPKciSB_
0000000000000000 W _ZN9log4cplus6detail17macros_get_loggerERKNS_6LoggerE
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6detail18get_macro_body_ossEv
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6Logger11getInstanceERKSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6LoggerC1ERKS0_
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6LoggerD1Ev
00000000000002c8 r _ZN9log4cplusL13ALL_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000002ac r _ZN9log4cplusL13OFF_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000002bc r _ZN9log4cplusL14INFO_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000002b8 r _ZN9log4cplusL14WARN_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000002c0 r _ZN9log4cplusL15DEBUG_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000002b4 r _ZN9log4cplusL15ERROR_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000002b0 r _ZN9log4cplusL15FATAL_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000002c4 r _ZN9log4cplusL15TRACE_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000002cc r _ZN9log4cplusL17NOT_SET_LOG_LEVELE
                 U _ZNK9log4cplus6Logger12isEnabledForEi
```

**Whith undefined references:**

```
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6detail16macro_forced_logERKNS_6LoggerEiRKSsPKciS7_
0000000000000000 W _ZN9log4cplus6detail17macros_get_loggerERKNS_6LoggerE
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6detail18get_macro_body_ossEv
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6Logger11getInstanceERKSs
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6LoggerC1ERKS0_
                 U _ZN9log4cplus6LoggerD1Ev
00000000000001ec r _ZN9log4cplusL13ALL_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000001d0 r _ZN9log4cplusL13OFF_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000001e0 r _ZN9log4cplusL14INFO_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000001dc r _ZN9log4cplusL14WARN_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000001e4 r _ZN9log4cplusL15DEBUG_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000001d8 r _ZN9log4cplusL15ERROR_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000001d4 r _ZN9log4cplusL15FATAL_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000001e8 r _ZN9log4cplusL15TRACE_LOG_LEVELE
00000000000001f0 r _ZN9log4cplusL17NOT_SET_LOG_LEVELE
                 U _ZNK9log4cplus6Logger12isEnabledForEi
```

---

#### Minimal class that fails

```
//////////////////////// Header ////////////////////////
namespace so {
namespace example {

class FailingExample
{
public:
    FailingExample(other_ns::Config* config, other_ns::Command* cmd);
    bool updateData(uint8_t* dataPtr, uint32_t dataSize);
    virtual ~FailingExample();

private:
    static const log4cplus::Logger logger;
};
}}


//////////////////////// Source ////////////////////////
namespace so {
namespace example {

FailingExample::FailingExample(other_ns::Config* config, other_ns::Command* cmd)
{
}

bool FailingExample::updateData(uint8_t* dataPtr, uint32_t dataSize)
{
    return true;
}

FailingExample::~FailingExample()
{
}

// Undefined reference to getInstance() here
const log4cplus::Logger FailingExample::logger = log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("FailingExample"));

}}
```

Comment: As can be  seen from the nm output  you have available get_instance("wide char string"), and you don't have the get_instance("c char string").

Comment: The `LOG4CPLUS_TEXT()` takes care of string types, unfortunately even using `std::string`, `std::wstring` or `log4cplus::tstring` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Inexplicably, adding a logger to one class may fail another class, that was working before. So adding a logger to class A causes class B not to find `getInstance()` anymore - even it was available before class A has been changed!?

Comment: Can't judge without a code.  Look at your list of requirements - the successful and erroneous. They differ in used get_instance().  Successful one links to the get_instance(std::string<whar_t>). Erroneous one links to the get_instance(std::string<char>). It means that get_instance(common char std::string) absent in your logging package.  That all which can be said without source code so far.

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov i have added a minimal example that fails with undefined reference to `log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(std::string const&)`. I' wondering why `std::string` is used btw.; the `LOG4CPLUS_TEXT(STRING)` macro expands to `L##STRING` so `std::wstring` should be used instead!?

Comment: It is interesting to see what will happen at compilation stage if remove get_instance(std::string) from the log4cpp header - why gcc choosed this version.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. The reason was a 3rd party library which defined `UNICODE` somewhere in it's headers, therefore it was defined in some files only (depending on headers included!?). *Detailed answer follows ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time of looking through source, i have found the cause - and the solution.

### The Root

Log4cplus uses either `char` / `std::string` or `wchar` / `std::wstring`, depending whether `UNICODE` is defined or not.

The eg. `LOG4CPLUS_TEXT()` macro handles these cases, it casts the string to the proper string type.

### The Problem

Although log4cplus was compiled using Unicode (and IDE showing proper preprocessor branches), the linker failed to link the correct `getInstance()` or other methods - sometimes, on some files!

At times he succeeded (using the `std::wstring` version) and then he failed;  the `std::string` version wasn't found, though it shouldn't be used actually.

Compiling log4cplus without Unicode support didn't work too (just the opposite type problem ...)

### The Cause

A 3rd party library - used in the project - had code like this deep in it's header-jungle:

```
...
#ifdef ...
#define UNICODE
...
```

*(note: `UNICODE` was not defined by the project)*

So the library defined `UNICODE` somewhere in a header - and if this occurs, log4cplus uses the `wstring` methods, otherwise the `string`.

This also explains why some files were working and some failed - depending on what headers it includes (and what those headers include by their own ... and so on ...)

If `UNICODE` use `wstring`, if not use `string` - used by log4cplus types, methods and macros (as LOG4CPLUS_TEXT() from above). Great if this behavior changes by some flag somewhere deep in another library ...

### The Solution

I only had to add a `-DUNICODE` to compiler flags and it was working! Log4cplus always uses `wchar`- / `wstring`-versions now!

*Regardless of this, the 3rd party library will be replaced in the future, maybe going back to non-unicode, but that's another story.*